# How to Authorize specific AWS Cognito users to be able to subscribe to AWS IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-iot

Basically what the title says, i am currently building an AWS Amplify front-end application where i want to get live data from AWS IoT topics. The thing is that i want only specific authorized users from Cognito user pool to be able to subscribe (attach specific AWS IoT policy for them).

Answer (score 1):

"I'm building an AWS Amplify front-end application where i want to get live data from AWS IoT topics"

This can be done using AWS. That is, you can develop a client application in a language such as React and have that client app authenicate with Amazon Cognito.

Then you can set up API Gateway to handle requests from the client app and use Lambda functions to invoke AWS Services. In your use case AWS IoT.

Now only authenticated users can make requests. The backend is Lambda functions that can invoke AWS Services and return data to the client.

See this illustration as an example:

[image]

See this AWS example as guidance:

[Create an application that analyzes customer feedback and synthesizes audio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/textract_example_cross_FSA_section.html)

Amplify does not play a role in the above solution. Only AWS SDKs (JavaScript SDK) and the services shown in illustration.

Comment: Yeah, thats right i have an architecture like this, just in my case i want to have (let's say) Premium users and Normal users with different privileges each. According to my understanding i will have to make 2 identity pools and assign different auth role to each pool. Am i thinking right?

Comment: You can use groups from user pool to identify the uses. Identity pool is kept for storing user specific information and it can be used for generating tokens for guest users.